# MySQL dump restore; verify integrity of restore

Tags: mysql

Below is how I am loading a 30gb dump file. What is the best way to verify it works? Should I check for errors in nohup.out? If an error happens will it stop?

```
 nohup mysql < all_db1.sql  &
```

Comment: One thing to do:  `SHOW TABLE STATUS;` in each database -- before and after.  They should look _similar_.

Comment: With 45,000 tables I am looking for a more automated way. Will replication always fail when I use it to catch up

Comment: Look through the Percona toolkit.